# Why I cannot get USSD notification but just an OK as a response from a GSM provider?

Tags: gsm, at-command

Hello I am trying to build some C++ application that is to transfer Credit from GSM network to another user.

The problem is: In my country we have "Djezzy, Mobilis, Oreedo" GSM providers.

So I've downloaded and tried first "Putty.exe" also "hyper-terminal" To test AT Commands before writing some C++ application based on those commands:

I tried Huewei E169 which is a USB GSM Modem. So in Oreedo provider we use the USSD code to get credit balance: "*200#". So I issue the command

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*200#",15
```

It returns me the balance of my SIM credit as a charm. But When I try to get "Mobilis" for example using the USSD code: "*222#" to get the credit balance I just got "OK" but no balance information is there.

The interesting thing is: If I use my Samsung Galaxy J5 as a usb modem (after installing its driver), after I use the USSD Code:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*222#",15
```

I got only OK on putty or hyper-terminal but I can see the USSD balance notification is on my phone!? although I requested it from an application running on my laptop?!!!

Please help. I am stuck here. What I want to do is to be able to get the balance or any query I do as I intended.

Does this belong to the GSM provider or some settings of the ports like listening or anything else I am missing.

Thank you all guys for your help and time. Any comment, advice, tip or answer is really highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The USB modem will take 3 different COM ports, try the command **AT+CUSD=1,"*222#",15** in the 3 comports, likely it will work well in one of them.